# Rename [the-stick-of-truth] → [south-park-the-stick-of-truth]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The game [*South Park: The Stick of Truth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park:_The_Stick_of_Truth) can be expanded to its full name, thanks to the 35 character tag name limit:

- [the-stick-of-truth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stick-of-truth) → [south-park-the-stick-of-truth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-park-the-stick-of-truth)

Comment: Especially because someone could always come up with questions which pertain to the Stick of Truth itself, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Done:**

- [the-stick-of-truth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stick-of-truth) → [south-park-the-stick-of-truth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-park-the-stick-of-truth)